# Less @import render one file for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, workflow, less, minify

I have several less stylesheets for my site.

My `style.css` file looks like this:

```
@import "../components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "./gist.less";
@import "./markdown.less";
@import "./main.less";
@import "./octicons.less";
```

I have a watch app that compiles everything nicely on save.

What I want is something like this for javascript. Where I can set one file, import everything that I want and I have one file that I can reference in html. I checked out require but I'm not sure how similar it is to this idea.

Is there any way to do this? I basically want a concatenate / minify javascript file holder like less. I guess I can build something that does this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: have looked at the less source? it has a couple of function for dynamically loading/refreshing less files

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I'm looking for some tool for compiling / minifying javascripts, that is less-inspired.

Comment: you mean stuff like the yui compressor? http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for here is [`browserify`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) or webpack. This post was from a while ago and that was before the popularity of these kinds of projects. But I think this is exactly what you were looking for. Here's [Browserify's first commit](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/commit/b0363ae3d5749b3f7e722b21c65484fdf634acf3) to note that it was around when this question was asked.